# Why does RxJS or Angular Observable subscribe method needs context?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Consider the following scenarios, where I'm passing a child Component a property updated later using a subscription to an RxJs Observable.

Angular is not detecting changes when not sending an anonymous function or biding the this context.

```
// Scenario 1
// Child component IS updated properly
this.someService.someObservable.subscribe((data) => {
    this.doSomething(data);
})

// Scenario 2
// Child component IS updated properly
this.someService.someObservable.subscribe(this.doSomething.bind(this))

// Scenario 3
// Child component is NOT updated properly
this.someService.someObservable.subscribe(this.doSomething)


private doSomething(data) {
    // this is executed on all the scenarios
    this.fieldPassedToChildComponent = data;
}
```

Why do we need to bind the context for angular to pick up the changes?

Comment: If you don't, the `this` inside `doSomething` evaluates to the global object.

Comment: You mean Scenario 2 works but 3 doesn't? That makes sense, because of how `this` works. `this` is decided when the function is called, unless you bind it.

Comment: @elclanrs you are right, edited it

Comment: This may be a duplicate since it is a very common question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Comment: @elclanrs yeah, I was just wondering why the this context is needed, and why I can't just pass my function as the first argument.

Comment: @CodeProX arrow functions don't create separate context and that's why it works. take a look at 'No Separate this' section here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Ok, Im referencing this inside doSomething thats why I need context. Thanks you all

Answer (score 2):

The problem with third case:

```
// Scenario 3
// Child component is NOT updated properly
this.someService.someObservable.subscribe(this.doSomething)
```

is that you cannot be sure what `this` keyword contains in your `doSomething` function on this line: `this.fieldPassedToChildComponent = data;`. It really depends how `subscribe` method calls your callback.

If you take a look in source code of `subscribe` you could find how the callback method is called and therefore what `this` is set to. My guess would be `undefined`. But could be anything. Therefore don't use this way.